# Django increment views + 1

Tags: django, templates, models

i dont know why this time i cant show the "number of views" of a items, i was doing this before but in this project i cant

```
def getAuto(request,marca,slug,id):
    from django.db.models import F
    object = get_object_or_404(Robado,marca__slug=marca,modelo__slug=slug,pk=id,publico=True)
    object.views= F('views')+1
    object.save()
```

template.html

```
views: {{object.views}}
```

The template.html is showing:

```
 (+: (DEFAULT: ), 1)
```

i cant imagine why

Thanks you guys

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think you can use `F()` like this. It's for use in `filter` expressions, where you can use it to compare one field with another field on the same model, and in `update` expressions, where you can increment a field in place:

```
Robado.objects.filter(foo=bar).update(views=F('views')+1)
```

but I don't see why you're trying to use it here, where you already have the object. It's easier just to reference the attribute directly:

```
object.views = object.views + 1
```

or even more simply:

```
object.views += 1
```